# Understanding Option.flatten in Scala

Tags: scala

I noticed that `Option.flatten` is [defined](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/Option.scala) as follows:

```
def flatten[B](implicit ev: A <:< Option[B]): Option[B] =
    if (isEmpty) None else ev(this.get)
```

What is `ev` here ? What does `A <:< Option[B]` mean ? What is it used for ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is common practice to constrain some methods to be executed against particular types. Actually, `<:<` is a type defined in `scala.Predef` as follows:

```
@implicitNotFound(msg = "Cannot prove that ${From} <:< ${To}.")
sealed abstract class <:<[-From, +To] extends (From => To) with Serializable
...
implicit def conforms[A]: A <:< A = ...
```

So that, implicit of type `<:<[A, B]` can be resolved only if A is a subtype of B.

In this case, it can be resolved only if `Option` in wrapped in another `Option`. In any other cases, compile error will occur:

```
scala> Option(42).flatten
<console>:8: error: Cannot prove that Int <:< Option[B].
          Option(42).flatten
                     ^
```

Comment: See also http://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html for a great in-depth explanation. I was particularly interested in what to do with the `ev` param, and this article explained it among other things. I've added to this answer to include that bit of info.

Answer (score 4):

As [ScalaDoc says](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Predef%24%24%24less%24colon%24less)  - `An instance of A <:< B witnesses that A is a subtype of B`.

So in this case an `Option` can be flattened only if it contains another `Option` inside.

An `Option[Option[String]]` flattens to an `Option[String]`

Answer (score 2):

`<:<` is a 'generalised type constraint' or 'type evidence'. These are supplied by the compiler and can be used to further constrain generic type parameters. In this case, the constraint is that the type `A` must be a subtype of `Option[B]` i.e. the option is a nested Option[Option[T]] for some type `T`.